# Disabling font color change when selecting ListView items

Tags: android, listview

I know there are a ton of questions regarding the highlighting of ListView items when clicking them already, and I've already managed to disable the background colour change (by setting it to transparent), but now the font itself is changing colour. I have my font colour as grey and I want it to stay that way even when selecting the ListView, but currently it's changing to black (because, I think, even if the highlight doesn't happen, the font colour still does). How can I disable this?

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/attendee_list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
    android:scrollingCache="true" >
</ListView>
```

Comment: try creating a 'selector' xml for listview in your drawable. never tried it but hope it works...

Comment: can you share your code

Comment: there is a cachecolorhint attritbutes in listview xml. please set this as android:cachecolorhint = "#00000000" .

Comment: @SAURABH_12, nope.. I've tried that before.

Ramkiran, there's nothing special in it, but edited accordingly.

Comment: You dont have a textSelector for the ListView Item correct. Are you supplying your own listItem or is android's? Ideally, font color should not change automatically. Can you provide the code for listItem as well or try putting a color say android:color/white or android:color/black for the background of listItem and check if it still changes.